# Android: trying to save a file

Tags: android

Im just trying to write a text file using this code:

```
    try {

        File ins = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "myfile");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ins);
        out.write(string.toString().getBytes());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried also this code:

```
    File aux = context.getFilesDir();

    String filename = "myfile";
    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(aux + filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem: Im not getting any error, but none of them are saving a file. I expected to find the new file at `/data/data/com.example.tirengarfio.myapplication/files`, since the output of `content.getFilesDir()` is that.

Moreover, I can not find a `/data/` folder at root but an `/Android/data` one, and inside of the latter, there are several directories like `com.android.browser` or `com.dropbox.android`, but none of them is named `com.example.tirengarfio.myapplication`.

Comment: Did you try /storage/emulated/data? Sometimes emulated doesn't exist or maybe things are being stored in the sdcard, but your files are probably inside /storage

Comment: how did you verify that the file is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need root permission to access `/data/data` from `adb`.

> but an /Android/data one, and inside of the latter, there are several
>   directories like com.android.browser or com.dropbox.android, but none
>   of them is named com.example.tirengarfio.myapplication

use [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) if you want to write in that directory. You need to add the write permission on the manifest

Comment: for me is ok to try to save the file at `/data` at this moment. I have downloaded a File Manager for Android and now I can see a different hierarchy like `/data` , `/dev`, `/devlog`.. But when I go to `/data` it says the folder is empty. I have added this line to `AndroidManifest.xml`:     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: the FileManager hasn't the permission to access /data. That's why don't see anything there

Comment: but I have root privileges at my smartphone, I checked it using an app.

Comment: did you run the FileManager with root privileges?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried also this code:

That will not work, as `aux + filename` is invalid, and your code will trigger some sort of `IOException`. Your first code snippet is better.

> I can not find a /data/ folder at root but an /Android/data one

That is because you are looking in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Internal storage is inaccessible on production hardware, but can be browsed on an emulator using DDMS's file explorer.

Comment: I have downloaded a file manager for Android and now I can see the the directories `/data`, `/dev`, etc.. But when I go to `/data` there is nothing inside.

Comment: @ziiweb: As I wrote, internal storage is inaccessible on production hardware, but can be browsed on an emulator using DDMS's file explorer. So, what did you download a file manager on? A device or an emulator?

Comment: I have just installed both, on device and also DDMS's file explorer, both rock! thanks!